# Cordapp configuration file with corda-node-driver

Tags: corda

I cant seem to find a way to load my cordapp configuration file when using the corda-node-driver.

The [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#using-cordapp-configuration-with-the-deploynodes-task) only shows how to load it with the deploy tasks. The deploy tasks are not an option for me.

Can this even be done using the corda-node-driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
...
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put("key1", "value1");
config.put("key2", "value2");

TestCordapp flow = TestCordapp.findCordapp("my.cordapp.flow").withConfig(config);
TestCordapp state = TestCordapp.findCordapp("my.cordapp.state");
driver(
    new DriverParameters(Arrays.asList(flow, state))
...
```

So instead of letting DriverParameters find the CordApps automatically, i provided them with a config.

Thanks to [Cais Manai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296853/cais-manai) for pointing me towards DriverParameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at writing a method that loads in your configuration file from local and then use the info loaded as input to the DriverParameters?

Comment: How would you input the info into the DriverParameters?

I need them to be available in the `CordappContext.config` to make them accessible from any given flow inside the cordapp